# SQL Server How to write query where one result should have first condition and rest conditions are optional

Tags: sql-server

I want to write a query where my results should contain atleast one result of first condition and rest conditions are optional.

I am trying something like this below..will this work

```
SELECT * FROM Student
WHERE Condition1
AND
(
Condition2
OR
Condition3
)
```

Below is my sample

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Student') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Student

CREATE TABLE #Student
(
    StudentID INT,
    IsActive BIT,
    IsPassed BIT,
    IsProjectDone BIT
)

INSERT INTO #Student
SELECT 1, 1, 1, 0
INSERT INTO #Student
SELECT 2, 0, 0, 1
INSERT INTO #Student
SELECT 3, 1, 1, 1
INSERT INTO #Student
SELECT 4, 0, 0, 0




SELECT * FROM #Student

-- SO I want atleast one record of Isactive =1  and other conditions such as (ispassed = 1, isprojectdone = 1 are optional
```

Comment: If you add sample data and expected results your question would make more sense.

Comment: Posted Sample of Temp Table

Comment: Based on the phrase " and rest conditions are optional" I would guess NO. The logical operator AND and the idea of "optional" are contradictory. But I will hazard a guess that you want to do something with optional parameters. If so, Erland discusses this [here](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html). Bookmark that site as it contains much useful information.

Comment: So in the result I want to see Student records of ID's 1,3 because  IsActive = 1 , also i should be able to see  student record : 2 because IsProjectDone = 1

Comment: @user1030181 Then apparently you want to use OR instead of AND?

Comment: The conditions of the where clause are applied to each row in the potential resultset. You want to keep a row if isactive = 1. You also want to keep a row if IsProjectDone = 1. So you need to use OR. Using AND means you want a row if isactive = 1 AND one of the other conditions is true.

Comment: Your sample query should work for what you want.  Does it not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean under "optional" as "not specified"?
If so, the following script should work. When @IsPassed and @IsProjectDone are declared, but not specified you will get all active students. If you specify those parameters you'll get additional filtering.

```
DECLARE @IsPassed BIT
DECLARE @IsProjectDone BIT

-- SET @IsPassed = 1
-- SET @IsProjectDone = 1

SELECT * FROM #Student
WHERE IsActive = 1 AND 
    (@IsPassed IS NULL OR IsPassed = @IsPassed) AND
    (@IsProjectDone IS NULL OR IsProjectDone = @IsProjectDone)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do with conditionally like this

```
Declare @Clientid int = 1
Select * from YourTable
where 
Col2 > 0  --(any true condition)
 or 
(isnull(col1,0) = @clientid or @Clientid is null)  --(any condition which may or may not true i.e parameter passed and it may be have proper value or null)


--Again run above query with clientid is null
Set @Clientid = null
Select * from YourTable
where 
Col2 > 0  --(any true condition)
 or 
(isnull(col1,0) = @clientid or @Clientid is null)
```

Or you can use [Exists](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_exists.asp) functionality of Sqlserver

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT column_name FROM table_name WHERE condition);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is how to get at least one record where Isactive=1 and other conditions such as (Ispassed=1, Isprojectdone=1) are optional.

**If the other conditions are optional, why even matter filtering the data by those conditions.**

You precised in an attached comment:

> So in the result I want to see Student records of ID's 1,3 because
>   IsActive = 1 , also i should be able to see student record : 2 because
>   IsProjectDone = 1

Based on your comment there is nothing optional about the conditions, you need to get all the students that fulfill at least one of your conditions.

Since your conditions are based on column of type BIT, you can do it like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM #Student
WHERE IsActive | IsProjectDone | IsPassed = 1
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Student
WHERE Condition1
UNION 
SELECT * FROM Student
WHERE Condition1
AND
(
   Condition2 OR Condition3 
)
```

Comment: Cant we do it in just one query instead of two queries and union all

Comment: but in your first query you are using AND between condition1 and condition2

Comment: I want results to have atleast one record of condition1.  Condition2 and condition3 records are optional

Comment: ..Posted Sample